# Pandas how to create a dataframe showing distance metric between every row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, that looks as follows:

[image]

I would like to make a 16x16 dataframe, df_distances, where I calculate the euclidean distance of [cx, cy] between every row with every other row. Diagonals will be zero as distance from row i's coordinates and itself is zero, etc.

In pseudocode, `numpy.linalg.norm(row_i[cx, cy], row_j[cx, cy])` for all i,j in range 1,16.

How can I do this without doing some painful double loop? Surely there is a smart and efficient way!

Comment: What kind of dataframe are you looking for? Seems to me you could just do scipy.spatial.distance.pdist to get the 16x16 matrix and then make a new dataframe from that.

Comment: Would that solution be able to use both the cx and cy columns? What would be the sample code? Feel free to put in an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able do it row-wise by broadcasting.

```
points = df[['cx','cy']]
distances = dict()
for i in range(1,17):
    point = points.iloc[i]
    distances[i] = np.linalg.norm(point - points)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is scipy.spatial.distance_matrix (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html). So you will create an numpy array with cx,cy columns and then pass that as both the x and the y to the distance matrix function

Comment: `d = df[['cx','cy']].to_array(); scipy.spatial.distance_matrix(d,d)`

Comment: @MoseWintner this worked for me, with some minor modifications. Changed to_array() to to_numpy() and then I cast the distance_matrix back into a pd.DataFrame which was convenient. Cheers